# Error: Type 'fluUint8List' not found. (flutter sdk problem)

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, flutter-dependencies

I tried to run my Flutter project and got this error. Because of this, my build failed.

```
../../Downloads/flutterInstalled/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_branch_sdk-6.3.0/lib/src/flutter_branch_sdk_method_channel.dart:328:16: Error: Type 'fluUint8List' not found.
      required fluUint8List icon,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried solutions online for this problem like `flutter clean` but still get these errors.

Comment: Upgrade flutter to the latest version

Comment: No I can't because other plugins work on 3.0.3 version

Comment: Did you change the source code in your local flutter sdk?

Comment: No I haven't made any changes there

Comment: You say that you didn't make any changes, but the evidence indicates otherwise: your `../../Downloads/flutterInstalled/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_branch_sdk-6.3.0/lib/src/flutter_branch_sdk_method_channel.dart` was (probably accidentally) modified, possibly from some errant search/replace operation.  I would recommend removing the entire `.pub-cache` directory tree and re-running `flutter pub get`.

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin I did what you told me to do i.e on my terminal I did  flutter pub cache clean. and then re- run the command flutter pub get still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for this question . The issue is with the file  flutter_branch_sdk-6.3.0/lib/src/flutter_branch_sdk_method_channel.dart the (import 'dart:typed_data';) well in the latest version its mistakenly commented the import  which created this whole problem .

Comment: I'm glad you fixed your problem, but this explanation does not make sense.  [The Git history](https://github.com/RodrigoSMarques/flutter_branch_sdk/blame/1ac419d17cfc4225a3816268078561e05c359d94/lib/src/flutter_branch_sdk_method_channel.dart#L328) shows no such typo on that line, and [pub.dev did not find any major problems with the package during static analysis](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_branch_sdk/versions/6.3.0/score).

Comment: https://github.com/RodrigoSMarques/flutter_branch_sdk/blob/master/lib/src/flutter_branch_sdk_method_channel.dart#L328 you can check this out you'll see import 'dart:typed_data'; is commented in the file well that caused the problem I'm using flutter version 3.0.3

Comment: Yes, but the problem you said you were having originally is that line 328 had a typo (`fluUint8List` instead of `Uint8List`).  That has nothing to do with the import.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).